# User deletes questions as soon as they get answer

Tags: support, specific-question

This has happened twice to me now and I'm sure it was [the same user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372724/priyanka-sarkar-2). I submitted an answer that was time consuming to prepare and the user immediately deletes the question once they have got what they want!

It seems to me they are abusing the system. I don't have the URL of the first occasion but the most recent question was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643624/tsql-to-find-the-start-and-end-dateset-based/4643790#4643790).

Comment: Good on you to recommend it here. Next time if you can, flag the question as well for the mods to review. They can take it from here.

Comment: I can't access the question to flag it anymore as only 10kers will be able to see it.

Comment: Indeed. but sometimes you have it cached ;)

Comment: @drachenstern - I did and it worked!

Comment: Besides that I already flagged this one which would get a mod to see it. I would advise not doing anything else at this point ;)

Comment: Discussed just yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interesting -- haven't seen this particular pathology before, but **definitely flag it and we will take action**. This is extremely community hostile behavior and will not be tolerated.

Comment: Thanks for taking action on this!

Comment: Any chance we can get [Diff is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75377/diff-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) back?

Comment: @arjan for what purpose? it has all been implemented. Open a new topic on the current UI.

Comment: For the very same reason as this very question is about? I cannot see *what* suggestions were made, but I'd like to see the shopping lists. (If there were any good suggestions? I cannot tell.) (As an aside: that very question is linked in [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75472/community-user-edit-how-does-it-know-what-to-edit) [places](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75581/is-everyone-in-favor-of-the-new-everyone-can-edit-idea). You might want to keep [the URL-within-Markdown search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76914) in place for yourselves and moderators!)