# Community♦ user edit: How does it know what to edit?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, community-user

I just noticed that the [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user edited a ~1 year old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2225265/revisions) of mine. As you can see, the method call was changed from `getSfGuardUser` to `getGuardUser`:

[image]

Now I checked the documentation and it seems that the edit is correct.

But *how* did Community know about that? As far as I know, it is an automated process. Does it have a reference of all possible APIs of languages/frameworks (which seems very unlikely) or is there a routine admins can trigger, for replacing content? Or is it a secret?

Comment: This is a chat conversation that might be relevant: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/testing-testing-1-2-3 - anon user edits show up as Community user edits. The 'feature' was turned on for a while to do testing, and is now off

Comment: +1 for `YEAH I WON!!! *happy-dance*`\

Comment: @YiJiang so outside users could edit Stack Exchange content?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not AI, but indentured digital sharecroppers :)

An upcoming new functionality that allows anyone to edit, then high-rep users to approve, was exposed briefly, and your answer was one of the lucky winners.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75377/diff-is-hard-lets-go-shopping

So, yes, it's a sort of secret. Or was.

Comment: In particular Community edits are from anonymous users.

Comment: Thanks :) Seems I have to spent more time on meta ;) Too bad it is not AI :D And: YEAH I WON!!! \*happy-dance\*

Comment: So I was searching meta and found this answer. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3952622/revisions) to my question got a Community ♦ edit too just yesterday. Did that answer win too?

Comment: It's so cool that the Community user edited this answer, lol :)