# Why are my suggested edits here approved by Community♦?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, meta, privileges, community-user

I just noticed that my suggested edits on meta are quickly approved by Community♦, sometimes almost instantaneously.

As a guess: does this have anything to do with the fact that I have edit privileges on the main site?

Comment: Indeed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/413, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/403, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/286 Nice!

Comment: I think the community user is becoming self-aware and will soon destroy us all and change its name to skynet

Comment: (As an aside, for whoever gets here because of the title: sometimes Community [seems to *make* edits too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75472/community-user-edit-how-does-it-know-what-to-edit). But that's due to non-registered users suggesting edits.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is caused by a reviewer choosing to change your edit, and once the edit dialogue is open, submitting without changing anything.

Answer (score 5):

I have to admit that, "No, that approve was from [ME](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541/you)" (<sup>Can't prove it but God knows that.</sup>).

Comment: Odd! In case of [a recent approval](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/412) by ChrisF, it shows [in his activity](http://i.imgur.com/15Cl3.png). No such thing [in yours](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541/you?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_reviews), but it does show [in Community's profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_reviews).

Comment: So, your name is YOU, so you'd possibly read that as "that approval was from YOU", and it'd be me, and... oh.

Comment: Are you choosing to improve but just submitting no changes?

Comment: @Grace, You are on to me ;)

Comment: And are [all these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_reviews) YOUrs then?

Comment: @Arjan, Nope, probably around 5, IIRC.

Comment: Sorry to rat on you, but [I had to do some further research and consequently report this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86612/improve-may-be-used-to-anonymously-circumvent-approval-requirements). What you've done here on Meta is rather harmless, but outside of here it is probably much more dangerous. You're more "accessory to the fix", if you think about it, for providing the existence of this flaw.

Comment: Not sure I feel comfortable accepting this answer, but +1 for honesty, I guess.

Comment: @BoltClock, you'll never have to accept anything on meta.