# Does the community user auto-approve some suggested edits on beta sites?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user, beta-sites

I noticed a lot of suggested edits on mechanics getting approved by the community like this example:

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/79

I found this question that points out that this is most likely someone clicking improve and making no changes just to get the edit through.

[Why are my suggested edits here approved by Community♦?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86604/why-are-my-suggested-edits-here-approved-by-community)

However, I found this question and accepted answer that makes me think this loop hole was closed:

["Improve" can fail to associate the approving user with the edit record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86612/improve-can-fail-to-associate-the-approving-user-with-the-edit-record)

So, is the loop hole closed or is this an exception or some sort of auto-approve for beta sites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, Community-User does not auto-approve. It is just because the fix of "Improve" lacks one checking for tag synonyms.

You have suggested "Check Engine Light" tag but the system has "cel" as synonym.

When approver choose "Improve" and without touching it, system assumed he did an tag edit to "cel", but actually he didn't. So, no new revision from approver, but yet approved.

This is the one I just reproduced on Formatting Sandbox post

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/821

May be you could say that there is another hole.

Comment: Nice catch.  I started looking at my other examples and found they all occurred before the fix of the first hole.  So I think this is exactly what is happening.