# Community approved a suggested edit, but no one "improved" the edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user

So, I know that when a user with the ability to approve suggested edits, [clicks *Improve* instead of *Approve*, if they got there first, the edit's marked as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80518/improved-edit-suggestions-approved-by-community)

> Approved by {me}, Community♦

That's cool. But [here's a case](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/173346) where I *didn't* click *Improve*. I'm *sure* of it. Well, *pretty* sure. I have been absent-minded today. <sub>Goes off to check</sub> Nope, definitely didn't. And I see:

[image]

What am I missing? Feature change? Did I suddenly aquire super-approve powers?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what's going on. [Looking at the question edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8737019/revisions), I approved the suggested edit at *exactly the same second* as the OP edited their post. So, in essence, the OP "improved" the edit. Makes sense. I'll wait for a more official answer, and I'll answer it myself if that's not forthcoming.

Comment: Community can actually accept suggested edits entirely on its own: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/171966 -- which it has done _a lot_ -- so there might be more to it. [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95507/157556) suggests another possibility...