# How does the "Community" user reject suggested edits?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, community-user

We all know StackOverflow is community driven, so edits are allowed. However users with low rep's edits must be approved in the suggested edits review area.

It is said that "Community" ***approves*** edits when a reviewer goes to edit your edit and then closes the edit dialogue without changing anything. 
- [Why are my suggested edits here approved by Community♦?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86604/why-are-my-suggested-edits-here-approved-by-community)

But how does "Community" ***reject*** an edit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically the same thing as for approvals, but the reviewer opts to improve the edit and unchecks the "suggested edit was helpful" checkbox.

The reviewer then gets credit for the final edit and the suggested edit is rejected by the Community "user".

Comment: I doubt this happened in this case, where the suggested edit [was made 15:38:05](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1171194), and the 2nd revision [was made at 15:39:11](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13843056/revisions), but did not even fix the title. I'd say it's an edit clash, silently rejecting the suggested edit, where both editors started editing before one was done?

Comment: Oh, maybe it was; it seems suggested edits always show the current title?

Comment: @Arjan The title edit didn't happen till 16:02, in the 3rd revision. When a suggested edit changes the title, [it shows up in the diff](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1066538). To me this looks like a suggested edit erroneously marked as unhelpful.

Comment: (You're right!)

Comment: It also seems to occur when you suggest an edit and then some other edit is approved before yours

Comment: On the other hand, Anna, why accept an edit that makes the title worse...? Is that some trickery from the editor, maybe because just changing tags is not enough to submit the suggestion? (This user does that [more often](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13665897/revisions), but surely not always.)

Comment: @Arjan An excellent question. I'm gonna go with "I probably didn't notice the title change at the time". :) Although I don't know if I'd say that adding a period at the end necessarily makes the title *worse*. I'm not sure off the top of my head if there are restrictions on suggesting a tag edit without changing anything else in the post.

Answer (score 2):

I've also seen Community reject an edit when the OP edits the post with a suggested edit hanging out there neither approved or rejected yet.

Comment: If I recall right, the OP is able to review suggested edits against their posts regardless of their rep level, so they shouldn't be able to edit while there's a suggested edit pending. Would you happen to have an example post handy by any chance?

Comment: @kate I assume you mean a simultaneous edit clash? I've seen those happen as well. Especially within the initial grace period. Where the OP makes an edit which somehow trumps an existing suggested edit made around the same time.

Comment: @AnnaLear http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/1126186?&_suid=1355703795757018097194838081343 is a community-rejected edit that was edited by the OP just at the time community rejected the (horrible) suggested edit.

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks. The OP's edit includes the contents of the suggested edit as well, so it looks like it was an "improve & reject" kind of thing as well. I wonder if we keep a record of this that I can look up to be sure. I'll check.