# Don't attribute edits by anonymous users to the Community user

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, community-user, anonymous

I saw in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75474/321647) that when an edit is made by someone anonymous and someone with sufficient rep approves it, the edit is attributed to the Community user.

I think it would be better if the system gave a more accurate account of what happened. For example, it could say:

> Edited by anonymous user, approved by [name of user].

Or if this is too messy, just say "Edited", and make it clickable so that people can find more information.

"Edited by Community" can seem misleading. When I saw it, I initially wondered who exactly had made the edit.

My suggestion is that it should be displayed on the post itself, not only hidden away in the revision history.

Comment: Nitpick: it's not edits by unregistered users that appear this way, it's edits by people who have no associated user at all; they are anonymous. The edit is attributed to Community because there's no one else to attribute it to.

Comment: 100% this. Instead of stopping at, "_[Stack Exchange sites are backed by a relational database, and many database entries require that there is a non-empty userid value. In cases where there is no user, `-1`, a.k.a. the Community User, is used instead.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258058/1028230)_" we should say, "_Hey, `-1` says it doesn't do human things. **It shouldn't own human actions.** Let's use `-2`, call that `UnownedEdits`, and have it own them instead._" (Fwiw, it apparently also happens for edits by deleted users.)

Answer (score 4):

There is a record. [Here is such an example:](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/posts/2623/revisions)

[image]
[image]

The edits you see are from a migration script. When Meta SO became Meta SE, the community user changes links to reflect the new migrated links, if I remember correctly. This is to prevent a large number of dead links from staying about.

---

Personally, I think including reviewer information makes the post too messy. It takes two users to approve a suggested edit (and three on some other sites, including SO). Including reviewer information right under the post will just clog it up with content, that not every needs to know. If someone needs to determine the information (which in most cases, will likely only need to be a moderator), it is trivially easy to get that information by looking at the revision history.

Comment: This also happens unrelated to migrations, though. And my suggestion is that it should be displayed on the post itself, not only hidden away in the revision history.

Comment: Migrations? The example that you linked to, is to fix bad links, as I specified in my last paragraph. Ah, I see you edited your question.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, it also happens in any case where an anonymous user has edited a post.

Comment: @Fiksdal So your question is only about approved anonymous edits, and not the scripts, right? (just to clarify things)

Comment: Yes. If it's actually done by an automatic process, then of course it's ok to attribute it to the Community user. My question is about situations where human beings edit and it gets attributed to the Community user.

Comment: @Fiksdal Okay gotcha :)