# delete your question if you don't get any usefull answer and re-post it? will it be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

After asking this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74609/mark-answer-as-not-answering-the-question and seeing its duplicate I realized that its high unlikely it gets implemented.

So I was thinking that if you don't get any useful answers you should delete your question and re-post it with more details. You should also add what you don't want to do(from the answers that did not answer your questions) and you get a better chance to get a real answer.

P.S. I know **some mods are crazy** and will try to **close the second question** even after you delete the first one saying stuff like "**you already asked that question**".

P.S. **There are some duplicates**, but really **old** ones and maybe some of you have grown up.

Comment: So, you're asking if reposting is appreciated, but before we can even respond you already know that some moderators are crazy and some of us needed to grow up...?

Comment: I said SOME, not ALL. Grown up part is for closers, I meant to say "please don't close it, since opinions might have change. the last duplicate is from 1,5 year ago."

Comment: see http://everything2.com/title/You+can+catch+more+flies+with+honey+than+with+vinegar

Comment: @Kobi: He should have at least worked "The mods must be crazy" in somewhere.

Comment: @Michael, ha! +1. The joke didn't hit me until the third or fourth time I saw your comment....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So I was thinking that if you don't get any useful answers you should delete your question and re-post it with more details. You should also add what you don't want to do(from the answers that did not answer your questions) and you get a better chance to get a real answer.

If the question has no answers or one weak answer:

You should edit the question instead to improve it. That will also bump it just like a new question; there's almost no difference since the `LastActivityDate` is what we look at in both cases.

If the question has multiple answers, but **because your question was unclear or of poor quality** you feel all the answers are inadequate:

It can be OK to ask a new question. But it *absolutely must* be significantly better, clearer, and more thoroughly researched than your previous question was. Garbage in, garbage out. [Asking a good, clear question is an art.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/)

And just to be clear: if you delete and repost questions with little or no changes, you risk being banned, potentially for life.

Comment: if I ask new question it will get closed as duplicate and it will make me feel bad(so this is not an option). I was talking about changing the question a lot and saying what you don't want.

Comment: so long as the new question is a *lot* better, as I said, this is probably OK.

Answer (score 3):

> ...you should delete your question and re-post it with more details.

## Don't do this.

You've already identified that the moderators (and most of us users!) frown upon this behaviour. This is with good reason - deleting and reasking removes any history, potentially deletes the work (answers) of other users and could be seen as gaming the system.

---

Instead, **you should edit the question** with more details, clarification of your requirements, why the answers you already have been offered don't help, etc - essentially add anything that will make it easier for others to answer your question.

If necessary add comments to the answers you have indicating *why* they didn't help, so that everyone can see the question really is unresolved.

As a side effect, this will also bump the question up the list so more users will see it.

Comment: for example I know a lot(i hope) about eclipse. If I see a question that I know the answer to I will answer it. However if that question has a lot of answers I won't even open it(why waste time reading it if I already know the answer?).

Comment: @01, I see where your coming from, and as per Jeff's answer it seems you can *possibly* get away with it in these circumstances. But frankly, if any question gets *lots* of answers and *none* of them help, it's indicative that the inital question was too vauge or generally poor. If a user needs to take this action on their questions more than a couple of times, they need to sharply reassess how they ask their questions.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting and reposting is not a good idea. See also [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented).

Its better to edit the question if you have more information.