# question vanished

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I answered a question earlier - with admittedly a guess at some things to try - the poster replied with a comment full of obscenities .

I was going to report it, but it seems to have vanished, there is no record of my answer, the downvote or my comments on my account. I assume that there is a super delete because somebody reported the comment?

Comment: Or your answer was not upvoted and was the only answer, which would allow the question asker [to delete the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471).

Comment: It was downvoted - but I though >10k uses could still see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the answer was downvoted, and the comments were beginning to descend into Lord of the Flies territory, we just nuked it from orbit.

Comment: Good - i thought I had imagined it .....

Comment: We need a visual of that process.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [recently deleted list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-deleted)? Deleted posts do not show up in profiles, even for 10k users.

Developers (and possibly moderators) can hard delete a post, but this is relatively rare.

Comment: (Access to /tools requires 10k or more.)