# Have the rules to delete your own question been changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete, self-delete

When trying to delete [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttJWe.png) of mine, which resulted because of a misunderstanding of how the election system works, I encountered this error:

> Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.
>
> (click on this box to dismiss)

The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) states that if there is only 1 non up-voted answer, you can delete your own question. Yet there is only one answer, and it is not upvoted. Have the rules changed or is something wrong?

[image: screenshot of not being able to delete my question]

Comment: This reminds me of when I ran into pretty much the same scenario in the old deletion rules. Oh, the memories of frantic experimentation to figure out just what exactly was preventing the deletion... ♪

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this is checked in and will be deployed this evening.

Comment: What was the issue, exactly, if I may inquire?

Comment: p.AnswerCount >= 1

Comment: Any idea where I can see the source code for SO?

Answer (score 3):

Well, per my answer at

[Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471)

This doesn't seem to match. I'll have to follow up with the code.