# Do I get back the reputation lost from downvotes on deleted questions?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, reputation-recalc

If you post a question and it gets downvoted, then you delete the question, will you get the reputation back at the next recalc?

How about if the same question also has an upvote? Will that be treated the same way, causing you to lose any reputation earned from it?

Comment: Yes[.](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Just don't do it too much to avoid getting the [ban hammer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, and you can [manually trigger a recalculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc) once per day at `/reputation`:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

Be aware though, that [you can only delete questions that have no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86616/no-way-to-delete-an-answered-question), though if it does have answers, you can flag it for deletion by a moderator.