# Unlinking a question from my account

Tags: feature-request, questions, creative-commons, post-disassociation

I have some questions with accepted and/or upvoted answers, which I would like to no longer associate with my account.

I know it is impossible to actually delete them. The rationale behind that is that people who've answered your question also invested value, and that the question is now not only your possession, but rather a useful item to the whole online community.

That makes sense. To some extent.

I believe that I should have the right to control my data, though.

It would be great if there was an option to, instead of deleting my question, I could just unlink it from my account.

This is what Disqus does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Shog9 says in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86618/213634) answer:

> Anonymize the question: Again, ask a moderator - they can delete your account completely, leaving all posts disassociated. Might want to change your username first... Be aware, this will also remove all of your votes and awarded bounties on the site, so you might end up inadvertently penalizing other users who've helped you in the past.

Shog's answer may sound like it is only possible to delete the question, but if you flag the question and request that you be disassociated with the particular question without getting your account deleted, that should be possible too.

And, as has also been suggested as [another duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/213634) for this question:

> If you would like to have your name removed from our use of the post, you can flag it for moderator attention. Moderators do not have the ability to change the ownership of the message, but they can bring it to the attention of a developer who may be able to reassign ownership to the Community user or some other "anonymous" entity.

Comment: I believe that [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/213963) would be another good one to quote/link for this answer.

Comment: @MichaelT: Updated my answer.

Comment: I was aware that something like this is possible. But contacting the staff doesn't seem like the optimal way of approaching this, so I flagged it as a feature request. But well, OK,I guess it's a duplicate...