# Removing SO questions by replacing title and content with "......................."?

Tags: discussion, questions, stack-overflow

Today I found question with title "..............." and content "..............."

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644935/make-int1-and-int2-become-int12)

I'm wondering, what you do in this situation?

I have selected last edit to return question back but need peer review because I have not enough reputation points for this action.

Somehow, Is it possible to protect questions of being removed this way by owners?

I've noticed that after I've found -15 rep in my profile (removed accept on my answer).

Comment: Approved your edit. Question should've been deleted using 'delete' by the owner. I guess there's no way to prevent that.

Comment: @halfdan: He probably won't have been able to delete the question since there are too many answers. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) for details.

Comment: Typical student trying to cover their tracks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention if there is a pattern of vandalism and the user continues to vandalise his posts, don't get into an edit war with the user. A moderator can stop the user from continuing the vandalism.

He probably can't delete the question because it has an upvoted answer, this protection is implemented to prevent users from deleting useful answers along with their questions.

There is nothing you can do about the accepted answer, though. That is solely the decision of the asking user.

Comment: Thanx. Well, my suggested edit is already accepted. I've flagged this question too minut ago.