# Why I can't delete my own question which has answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

I can delete my own questions without any answer. why am I not able to delete my own question, when it has an answer?

Comment: To which question are you referring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) Specifically, see [this explanation by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471).

Comment: NO ITS NOT THE DUPLICATE ITS MUCH DIFFERENT FROM THAT @Popular demand

Comment: Nonetheless, if you read the answer to that you'll have the answer to this.

Comment: Yeah, "close as duplicate" works a little bit differently on Meta. If you can find a `[faq]` entry that addresses the question, it's okay to close, even if it's not truly a duplicate.

Comment: You **can** delete your own question if the only answer it has is one which you have posted yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you'll effectively delete the answer as well. The answer can't exist without a question. Since this could lead to abuse, you don't have the ability to delete other people's content. If someone answered your question, the answer might be useful for other people also. If you believe the whole question and its answers should be removed for any reasons, flag them for a moderators attention.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete your question, if there is at least one answer that has been up-voted, or accepted. If the answer has been accepted, you should first not accept it; if you voted the answer, you should first remove your vote on that answer.

In the case you cannot delete your own question, you can flag it for moderation attention, and report the exact reason why you want it deleted; if you give a detailed reason, and if the moderators agrees with you, then they will surely delete your question.

As moderators handle many flags, and adding noise when not necessary doesn't help them, only flag the question for a very valid reason. If your reason for deleting the question is merely to get back the reputation you lost on the question, then that is not a valid reason, IMO.

[image: screenshot]