# Delete own question with answers: flagging and close votes

Tags: support, questions, flags, vote-to-close

I asked a question on SO ([R independent columns in matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943422/r-independent-columns-in-matrix)) several months ago and I don't think it is a good question. It is less about programming and more the understanding of the mathematics of the problem.

I don't think the question adds any value and should be deleted.

Since it has answers I cannot delete it myself. I flagged it and the flag was deemed "helpful". Nevertheless, it was not closed and I voted to close the question. Now it has one close vote. How can I make sure this question gets deleted?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103904/why-i-cant-delete-my-own-question-which-has-answer