# Please allow us to leave comments on deleted questions and answers

Tags: feature-request

Recently, I helped a fellow stacker investigating a problem he thought was with generated QR codes. The *real* problem appeared to be with HTTP server redirect codes:

[Why does a QR Code with a Yourls url go to two different locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733952/why-does-a-qr-code-with-a-yourls-url-go-to-two-different-locations)

The user deleted the question after leaving a comment to the effect that replacing the QR code generator 'solved' the problem. Deleting the question took away a decent answer that sadly had languished with no upvotes. (It's not great, but it did answer the specific question. I'd give it an upvote had I seen it in time...)

I want to leave a comment on the question explaining that deleting questions is impolite. But I cannot leave a comment on the deleted post. Since I'm just a user, I have no access to the moderator-only messaging system.

Please let us leave comments on deleted questions and answers. (I've wanted to tell people to undelete specific answers before; leaving a comment on another answer seems silly, but worked before...)

Comment: While the general problem hasn't been resolved, the mentioned question has been reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've deleted a post, you won't receive any new notification about it (unless you or a moderator decides to resurrect the post). This is important; otherwise people who've written and later rescinded controversial posts would see their inbox flooded forever.

Your recourse, if you see a question that you think shouldn't have been deleted, is to flag it and ask a moderator for undeletion. Say that you would have upvoted the answer (thus preventing the deletion) if you'd seen it in time. The moderator will use their best judgement to decide whether to resurrect the question.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as Accepted because it raises a counter argument to my proposal, one I can completely sympathize with. I'd still like a general facility to notify people about deleted posts, but flagging for moderator attention seems to be The Preferred Mechanism. So be it. :)

Answer (score 7):

Questions that have no upvotes or upvoted answers can be deleted by the OP, by design.  It may seem rude to you, but zero score questions are not protected by the system, because the community has not deemed them valuable by bestowing upvotes on the answers that are posted to them.

In other words, self-deletion is a good thing; it cleans up the noise.  Once an answer to a question receives upvotes, it establishes some community ownership, and the system will prevent the OP from deleting the question.

If you really feel compelled to say something about it to the OP, leave a comment on one of his other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Should the question actually have been deleted (See [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented))?  If not, vote to undelete or flag a moderator to have it undeleted (if you have 10k or are the OP and have a link). When it gets undeleted, you can then leave your comment.

If it's a really important comment and the question should be deleted (which is...not likely), a mod can undelete it, leave a comment (which will be delivered to the users' inbox), and re-delete it.