# Deleting own question should be somehow limited

Tags: discussion, self-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented)

I read the comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9933825/684229):

> Why did you delete stackoverflow.com/questions/9936151/… ? I thought it was a good question and it got a good answer.

Let's imagine you see great question, you put some effort to your answer and then the OP from some reason decides to delete the question.. I think this should be somehow limited, because 
once there are answers to the question, **the OP not only deletes his work, but also work and effort of others**!

This might especially happen in newbies, which are not yet caught by the "reputation craving" :-) I asked question, got answers, I don't need it any more - so delete it.
Also users with high rep might be tempted to delete some questions in order to increase their accept rate... or some questions when they can feel they appear "stupid", but 
these questions are good lesson for others.

So I feel there should be some limits when the question cannot be deleted. Just thoughts:

1. question which has answers
2. question which has answers of more than X upvotes (total or maximum)
3. question with at least 1 upvote
4. OP has reputation less than Y
5. favorited question

What do you think?

Comment: Some of these rules already exist: [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented) (and then especially [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) there).