# Question deleted by the poster because the issue is resolved?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

[This question (10K link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642670/mysql-trigger-on-insert-to-limit-the-number-of-expired-passwords-stored) was deleted after I made a comment and the poster replied that it solved the problem. Should it be undeleted?

Also, is that OK that I post this on Meta? I mean, the poster has the right to remove their questions, but I think they misunderstand when it should be done.

Comment: PS:  [the question was just undeleted](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10642670/revisions), so answer away! (Quick, in case it is closed as "Too Localized".)   ;)

Comment: @BrockAdams OK, if you say so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has over 500 rep, so he/she presumably knows the ropes. And that question was borderline "Too localized", IMO, so maybe it is okay to be deleted.

It was kind of an inconsiderate move, sure.  He should have let you post your answer as an answer and get bazillions of upvotes (^_^), but he didn't -- Them's the breaks.

And, yes, it's okay to post a question like that here, but there's a chance it is a "duplicate".

Comment: Source for the breaks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471

Comment: Yeah, I thought about looking at the poster's profile before asking, but I couldn't find a link to it.