# Question deleted with an answer?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I was under the impression that a question could not be deleted by its owner once an answer had been posted, but this appears to have happened

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129372/how-to-replace-all-empty-history-messages-on-windows

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Comment: Though surely the answer to this Meta question is in the duplicate, I do feel your pain if you answered that deleted question. Sometimes someone steps in to undelete such questions, but since a moderator did see this very Meta question, I guess that's not going to happen. Still then, [simply asking the OP for the why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129380/how-to-view-content-of-commit-id-shown-by-git-rebase/16129505#comment23041823_16129380) doesn't hurt. Or vote for [Disallow deletion of questions for 24 hours after last answer was posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135538/)?

Comment: @Steven-penny, ouch. That's a pity when one works on neglected questions like you. I proposed a gold badge for that pattern, how should deleted questions be considered? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268