# Question removed by OP after I answered it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, undelete

The OP removed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479928/spring-global-path-variable-or-request-parameter-without-controller/30481078#30481078) after I posted an answer (*and an useful edit*) to it. Not sure if this is too un-common as I faced it only second time. (*can't get the first instance details as it was couple of months back*)

Is there any way I can get the details why the question was removed either by the OP or community mods?

Also should this behaviour be reported because I feel the answer did help the OP and could be useful for future readers.

Comment: That's not nice of the OP, voted to undelete. Anyway, he left [this comment before deleting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx3PW.png) - which still doesn't explain why he deleted. You can try and contact the OP in chat, he has a [chat profile](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1321564/benjamin-m) - you can just click "Start a new room with this user" and wait. :)

Comment: Well, now that the question is undeleted you can just ask the OP in a comment.

Comment: Thanks ShadowWizard & TimPost for help :) Just asked OP for reason of deletion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disallow deletion of questions for 24 hours after last answer was posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135538/disallow-deletion-of-questions-for-24-hours-after-last-answer-was-posted)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I added my (binding) undelete vote on top of the other that was left. The system allows for this, you can delete your own questions whenever:

- It has no answers
- It has only one answer that isn't positively scored

This is designed as the best compromise to allow folks to remove questions that they *probably* didn't mean to ask in the first place without *much* risk of wasting someone else's time.

The check in the process is that high-rep users *can* cast votes to undelete something, which is what happened here, I merely added mine to push it over the edge.

The *nice* thing to do in cases like this is to simply request disassociation from the question, or any time you see that someone spent more than a trivial amount of time trying to help you. But that's not obvious at all to users.

We *really* need a self-service means of doing this that won't also interfere with rate limits and blocks due to poorly-asked questions. I've had this on my list to design for months, it's about time I get to it. If that was in place, we could prevent self-deletion once *any* answer over a certain number of characters has been posted, since 10k+ users and the automatic cleanup scripts generally take care of removing stuff that just plainly isn't useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I vouch for the feature  you propose.