# People ask a question and delete it!

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I answered a question, and the asker deleted it after I answered it. A solution would be to make the asker lose reputation if he deletes a question with at least 1 answer. By the way, I think he deleted the question because it had -2 votes.

Comment: If your answer receives upvotes, the OP cannot delete the question. Also, if such a question asker keeps deleting downvoted questions he or she will be question blocked automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An OP can only delete a question if it hasn't got any upvoted answer on it, or more than one answer. Unfortunately your answer had not yet received upvotes.

I don't think penalizing question askers for deleting a bad question is a very good idea either though. When they ask a bad question, then delete it they are helping keeping the site clean. If question deletion would cost reputation we'd have to clean up many more crappy questions.

That said, we don't want to encourage such behaviour too much. Note that if such a question asker keeps deleting downvoted questions he or she will be blocked automatically from asking any more questions.

Comment: I agree, but it doesn't seem fair that an OP is able to delete my answer 3 mins after I answer his question. There should be a minimum time, to let other SO users vote for the question and the answer before letting the OP delete the whole question. Or maybe let the OP delete the question only if his question and all the answers have negative score instead of no votes (zero score).

Comment: What then? If the question was of terrible quality, chances are that it'll get deleted *anyway*, and then you just loose the reputation again. It happens from time to time. SO is about quality questions and answers, reputation comes second to that. In other words: rep is nice, but don't get too attached to it. The goal is to have great questions and answers, and reputation is only a tool towards that.

Comment: Well, I never used the word "reputation", What I really care about is the content, and it doesn't seem Ok that the OP has full control over it until someone comes around an vote something. Which may not be much time if the OP is fast enough. BTW, why are you implying it had bad quality? Zero votes on the question + zero votes on the answer != bad quality.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: No, but advocating a minimum age barrier on being allowed to delete a question needs to take quality problems into account. We need to think general here, not specific.

Answer (score 5):

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> You **can't** delete any question that:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes), or
> - has been closed less than 48 hours ago (to allow for possible reopening)

In your case the question was probably not that good (score -2) and the poster regreted posting it. It is just fair that he/she can delete it.

For the cases mentioned above there is a delete protection already in place.

Comment: @Runemoro: That seems a little paranoid to me.

Comment: @rune if the question was that bad, it would likely have been closed and deleted anyway. You could have gained rep, but lost it regardless.

Comment: @Runemoro if the author does that intentionally and often, they will be stopped by the system. See [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74466)

Comment: What do we learn from all that? You should not try to answer bad questions. It encourages to ask them.