# So I want to delete my bad question for posterity's sake

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21979563). I realized as I was making a fiddle to try and display the problem what my error was (a completely unrelated bug in my code.) Someone had already (valiantly) tried to answer so there is an answer so I can't delete the question. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: This is part of the reasoning: [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74466)

Comment: This blog post is the "original source": http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/

Comment: @Pëkka I understand but if you look at Jeff Atwood's answer it says a post can be deleted if there is one answer with a score of 0 then it can be deleted. In this case there are two answers with a score of 0. One of which I flagged because it is a link. As I said kudos to the other guy

Comment: If they have upvotes, even if the score is zero, it'll stop you deleting the question.

Comment: @Emracool the only one with an upvote should be flagged and removed (I have already flagged but don't have the privileges to delete it)