# Why is possible for some answered questions to be deleted on some SE sites but not on others?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, answered-questions

It didn't fit in the title, but I'm talking about questions answered by others, i.e. not self-answered . On some SE sites (e.g. politics, if I recall correctly) one cannot delete his own question that has been answered by others, while on other SE sites (e.g. on psychology) such an action is possible. Why this difference? Is there a site-wide flag controlling this behavior?

Comment: I'm not aware of any difference. Did you check the score of the answer(s)? Having a single <1 scoring answer doesn't prevent the question from being deleted, but if it's upvoted or there are multiple answers, then it can't be self-deleted.

Comment: @Laurel: I think the difference might be the presence of multiple answers (between the cases I know). It's somewhat weird because the help/popup message only says something like "you cannot delete question others have spent time answering" (paraphrasing from memory).

Comment: It's more complicated than whether it's answered or not. The answer has to have at least one upvote. This is network wide policy and is outlined in the FAQ I've closed this as a duplicate of in the "When can't I delete my own post" section.

Comment: @Catija: thanks, I see an alternative rule preventing deletion is "has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)", so Laurel was also correct..

Comment: Yep. :) Either is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "business logic" so to speak, of question deletion for most part is universal. As far as I know, there's no update from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74471/135565), but as long as there's more than a single answer, or if that single answer is upvoted, self-deletion of questions is not possible.

Depending on the site though, and your reputation, its entirely plausible the question *wasn't* self deleted, or there's some odd edge cases going on (do deleted *answers* count, for example).

That said, the behaviour here ought to be consistent everywhere